# Get a column of list of indices showing which rows are equal in a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe:

```
np.random.seed(42)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 5, size=(10, 1)), columns=['col0'])
```

ie

```
   col0
0     3
1     4
2     2
3     4
4     4
5     1
6     2
7     2
8     2
9     4
```

I would like to get a column indicating in each row the indeces of all the rows with the same value as the given row. I do:

```
df = df.assign(sameas = df.col0.apply(lambda val: [i for i, e in enumerate(df.col0) if e==val]))
```

I get:

```
   col0        sameas
0     3           [0]
1     4  [1, 3, 4, 9]
2     2  [2, 6, 7, 8]
3     4  [1, 3, 4, 9]
4     4  [1, 3, 4, 9]
5     1           [5]
6     2  [2, 6, 7, 8]
7     2  [2, 6, 7, 8]
8     2  [2, 6, 7, 8]
9     4  [1, 3, 4, 9]
```

Which is the expected result. In my real world application, the `df` is much bigger, and this method does not complete in required time.

I think the runtime scales with the square of the number of rows, which is bad. How can I do the above computation faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to groupby `col0` and convert the grouped index to list

```py
df['sameas'] = df['col0'].map(df.reset_index().groupby('col0')['index'].apply(list))
```

```
print(df)

   col0        sameas
0     3           [0]
1     4  [1, 3, 4, 9]
2     2  [2, 6, 7, 8]
3     4  [1, 3, 4, 9]
4     4  [1, 3, 4, 9]
5     1           [5]
6     2  [2, 6, 7, 8]
7     2  [2, 6, 7, 8]
8     2  [2, 6, 7, 8]
9     4  [1, 3, 4, 9]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just do `groupby` with `transform`

```
df['new'] = df.reset_index().groupby('col0')['index'].transform(lambda x : [x.tolist()]*len(x)).values
Out[146]: 
0             [0]
1    [1, 3, 4, 9]
2    [2, 6, 7, 8]
3    [1, 3, 4, 9]
4    [1, 3, 4, 9]
5             [5]
6    [2, 6, 7, 8]
7    [2, 6, 7, 8]
8    [2, 6, 7, 8]
9    [1, 3, 4, 9]
Name: index, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. Would you be able to add some more explanation in what the `[x.tolist()]*len(x)`part is doing? I am confused about why `df.reset_index().groupby('col0')['index'].transform(lambda x: x.tolist())`does not work (I tried now, it doesn't), as I thought `x` is a group of indeces. Your syntax does work.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(42)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 5, size=(10, 1)), columns=['col0'])
df
'''
   col0
0     3
1     4
2     2
3     4
4     4
5     1
6     2
7     2
8     2
9     4
'''
```

get a Series as mapping:

```py
ser = df.groupby('col0').apply(lambda x: x.index.to_list())
ser
col0
1             [5]
2    [2, 6, 7, 8]
3             [0]
4    [1, 3, 4, 9]
dtype: object
```

use mapping:

```py
df.assign(col1=df.col0.map(ser))
'''
   col0          col1
0     3           [0]
1     4  [1, 3, 4, 9]
2     2  [2, 6, 7, 8]
3     4  [1, 3, 4, 9]
4     4  [1, 3, 4, 9]
5     1           [5]
6     2  [2, 6, 7, 8]
7     2  [2, 6, 7, 8]
8     2  [2, 6, 7, 8]
9     4  [1, 3, 4, 9]
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

On-liner method:

```
df['col1'] = [df[df.col0.values == i].index.tolist()for i in df.col0.values]
df
```

Output:

| index | col0 | col1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 3 | 0 |
| 1 | 4 | 1,3,4,9 |
| 2 | 2 | 2,6,7,8 |
| 3 | 4 | 1,3,4,9 |
| 4 | 4 | 1,3,4,9 |
| 5 | 1 | 5 |
| 6 | 2 | 2,6,7,8 |
| 7 | 2 | 2,6,7,8 |
| 8 | 2 | 2,6,7,8 |
| 9 | 4 | 1,3,4,9 |